# how to put a gtk window at dockable level in wayland?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, wayland

I am trying to put a GTK3 / C dockable window on wayland I am using glade and in the window properties I have placed dockable. When I start the program on X11 it works perfectly, but when I start on wayland it starts as normal window, is there any special code that allows to do this on wayland with GTK3 and c language?